# SVG not working on Android browsers. Can't debug it

Tags: javascript, android, svg, get, xmlhttprequest

So I am making this SVG

https://hostr.co/file/ZEfhLiQokslY/ps4Countdown.svg

and it is just supposed to be a simple countdown clock. And it works fine in any other platform I've tested it in. And I'm, even told it works on the iPad(not sure though). I made another one that has a set time, here:

https://hostr.co/file/PLCY7lodb7Lk/xboxCountdown.svg

which works fine. So I am guessing since the only differences between the 2 version is their file name, their CSS, one of the symbols, and the way I get the date for the countdown, I'm guessing it's the way I get the date, since that uses a `GET`, and `XMLHttpRequest` to another site, on the version that isn't working.

My issue is I apparently am incapable of setting up ADB, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to debug this other than through that, so can anyone offer some insight?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Finally got ADB to work. Goodness that was annoying. The issue was the drivers. Had to go through some serious hoops to get them too.

EDIT2: It also turns out that the problem was in the XMLHttpRequest. I guess Android browsers don't like it, but they apparently like Google's Geocoder. :/

Comment: Have you tried [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/)?

Comment: doesn't seem to work on windows

Comment: Well I haven't used it on windows, but I know that lots of people do.

Comment: alrighty. I'm giving it a shot, but god damn is this a seriously over complicated way to just find out what error Im getting on my phones browser

Comment: No argument there!  Debugging phones is like a trip back to 1982.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default Android browser, or Chrome?  If the latter, then you can remote debug Android Chrome via the desktop Chrome dev tools.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Thanks. I just got it working. It turned out I needed some obscure driver from the depths of samsung's website.